# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named spacy.training

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy, spacy-3

Hi I am trying to import Example class from Spacy.training module. I am trying exact code as in documentation.

```
from spacy.training import Example
```

But I am getting "`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy.training`'"
How can I import Example class now?

Comment: What is the version of your spacy?

Answer (score 4):

`Example` was introduced in `spacy version 3`.

Link to `Example` https://spacy.io/api/example#_title

You can check the current version of your spacy with this command on your Jupyter cell:

```
!pip show spacy
```

OR

```
spacy.__version__
```

Once you check the version, you can  update to a latest version by:

```
!pip install -U spacy
```

Once, you get `spacy 3` your problem will be resolved.

Comment: thank you so much this solved the issue

Comment: Please accept my answer! by clicking green arrow